# IdentityServer frontend displaying with missing structure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I created an empty asp.net core web app that has identityserver4 set up in the program. For some reason when I run the program the browser looks like this

[image]

instead of how it should look like

[image]

The program was not running on **.net 6.0** because it was saying could not find the /index but I downloaded the templates of IdentityServer4 by running the cmds `dotnet new -i identityserver4.templates` and `dotnet newis4ui` which gave me the UI which includes the `/index`. See [this github for identityserver UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI). **So I then switched it from .net 6.0 to .net 5.0 in the project property settings which worked but displayed this weird format.**

`startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddTestUsers(Config.Users)
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());
        }
    }
```

**Is there a reason why it is displaying as shown in my first screenshot and not as the second one?** I cleared my cache and deleted my cookies on my browser thinking that would help but it didn't.

Comment: Try adding `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your `Configure` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshots you provided it is seen, that none of `js` or `css` files are loaded. You have to add `app.UseStaticFiles()` before `app.UseRouting()`. That will fix the problem

Comment: Thank you! It definitely fixed the problem!